# How to validate user name

Tags: java, android

Iam working on an application where users can login with their user name. So i want to restrict the user when choosing their user name.
The user name must only contain lower case letters with no white spaces.
How do i do that.

Comment: (1) Loop over all characters, (2) check if it is lowercase letter, (3) the first time you find incorrect character validation can return false. Are you having problems with any of those steps?

Comment: you can do something like below:- etUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim()

Comment: @RudraRokaya That isn't validation per se, that's modification, and doesn't handle inner spaces (e.g., `"my user name"`). If the user name is *modified* it would be critical to re-display it to the user for validation: "Phil Accio" reads more like a name than "phillaccio".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex pattern: `[a-z]+`.

```java
String pattern = "[a-z]+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( pattern );
System.out.println( p.matcher( "AbAD ADD" ).matches() ); //This will NOT match
```

The pattern allows only lower case alphabets. So no space as well.